How do I justify a society where people have two permanent homes: a summer home and a winter home?
In medieval societies, fresh food was usually not available during the winter, because nothing could be grown or harvested.
I propose the idea of traveling south for winter, like geese, but not in a strictly nomadic way. People would migrate between two specific permanent homes. During the "summer", they'd live in a colder climate, growing crops for about 6 months. Then, when the very last crops are harvested, they'd head south to a warmer climate, where they could grow crops and live for the "winter". Villages would have a "twin" village, where basically their whole population shifts between, with the same residents in each at any given time, albeit with different layouts of houses and streets.
How would I justify such a society? Is it plausible? Is there anything I should consider to make it work?

Transhumance.

Besides my slightly flippant now deleted thought, you've never heard of migratory tribes and societies, hunter gatherers and herders, some of who still persist to this day .. apparently? it doesn't need a lot of fanciful justification when you have real world examples to draw on.

These aren't migratory tribes or hunter gatherers though, that's my whole point.

A lot of people in Norway have two homes, the main home and the holiday home. Many people in the US have two homes. Look at numerous vacation places in the US and see the society that migrates there seasonally.

Does absolutely everyone have to leave?  Can there be guards and caretakers who are, while few, still a distinct proportion of the population?

@AlexP if you think you know an answer, please use the answer section. The comments are to improve or clarify the question.

@Trioxidane: Comments are ephemeral. They are not made for the purpose of improving or clarifying the question. The purpose of comments is to indicate to the querent that they need to improve or clarify the question. In particular, the question needs to be improved by contrasting the request with the very well known and widely distributed practice of transhumance.

@AlexP comments help center. If you wish to leave constructive criticism or minor transient information, I would advice you to do it in a clear manner. A single link is by this example easily misinterpreted, or at all clear. Though I struggle to see the contrast, as it could be used as an answer to the question.

Another reason besides agriculture is that humans don't like extreme heat/cold either. In Italy, Greece etc. it's not uncommon to move to a holiday house at the beach over summer, because the heat in the city is just intolerable.

I suspect that you can justify this in a myriad of ways. However this site has a requirement of asking questions that don't have many equally valid answers.

Decadence requires money not justification.

It's my understanding that migratory birds also have quite specific territory they return to at each end of the migration (barring habitat change).

Apart from the concept already being established in the real world, if you want your fictional world to have this, it can have this. You don't need to justify it towards this reality, since you already have a clear reasoning in-universe.

simple way to make this migration easier, is to establish the civilization along the banks of a giant river, for example with the Northern pastures and farmland being upriver, and generally perfect in the warmer months, while the Southern delta of the river being perfect for colder months farming, or if not farming, maybe fishing?

Pastoral societies or groups more or less do this already: to ensure shelter and food for their livestock, they move back and forth between two locations, one being the summer/good season one and the other being the winter/harsh season one.
On the European Alps for example is common for shepherds to bring their animals up during summer and down during winter, but in their case the village stays behind.
If you really want the whole village to follow, it means that livestock is the primary or sole means of sustenance and that you are much more strongly dependent on natural resources for livelihood. It's very likely therefore that tribes and bloodlines will more important than villages.

But it would be a lot easier for those that depend only on livestock to not have permanent homes - why should they? A permanent home is a burden for such a civilization. And if they want shelter, they eventually would invent/construct a yurt, ditching permanent home for freedom to roam the lands, as well as the ability to escape draught, for example.

In Mongolia it is common to have three spots: winter, spring/autumn, summer. Winter spots usually have some permanent structures (at least for livestock), the other spots only sometimes.

@Vesper, the simple answer to this is that the people who herd the animals often have family who do other things. For example, in the American west it was common form men to drive cattle across the country and to leave their wives and children behind doing other tasks, such as arable farming. A permanent home also provides a base for the storage of goods and provisions for off seasons, or a place to winter over.

@Vesper unless there's no advantage of going anywhere and you end up switching  between the same two places anyways. Why not build more permanent structures there if you know you'll be back next year anyway? Sure, the houses won't be as big and/or may just be foundations to put the yurts on, but slowly two villages will evolve

@AaarghZombies Very interestingly, this is the exact opposite division of labour compared to that traditional in central Sweden: here the women would tend and milk the cows at the summer residences, while the men stayed behind. There supposedly was some reluctance to leaving young men alone in the woods with the animals, for fear of "unnatural" behaviour... The men stayed at home at the fields.

@EdvinW, my understanding of it was that tasks such as milking cows was seen as being a woman's task because it was physically easier, while men tended the fields because it was physically harder. I think that bit about unnatural behavior mostly comes from modern adult entertainment.

@AaarghZombies there are depictions of that unnatural behavior in antique artistic production, and the myths of the Minotaur and Leda also talk about that behavior. I think we can for once shift the blame from modern adult entertainment.

@L.Dutch, None of which involved Swedish farmers.

@L.Dutch I don't know this was the same in all of Europe, but parallel to our witch processes there was a wave just as large of accusations of bestiality. The cases where often about as strong as against the witches, and by some accounts more men were executed for this than women for witchery. In this social environment, it makes perfect sense for parents to not want their teenage son herding their livestock. It just isn't worth the risk. Anyone breaking this norm is noticed, and you end up with a culture where it's simply the women and girls who take care of the cows.

The idea is pretty good, but there is one problem with it:
There are easier ways of getting food in the winter
While you wouldn't have fresh food, you don't really need it. After all, even today, think about how much food we eat is processed and/or preserved. While people during the Middle Ages obviously did not have access to the same preservatives as us, they still had salt, which is a highly effective preservative. Heck, grains, the staple food for nearly all cuisines, can be stored without salt and not spoil. To survive the winter, you just have to grow enough food in the summer and salt what you need.
In the society you built, to survive the winter, you would have to grow enough food for the journey, make the long trek to the warmer climate, hope no unsavory characters made your winter home a base of operations, and rebuild the town (because it probably fell into disrepair during the summer).
Then, assuming everything went well, you would do it all again in the spring. That's not even taking into account any bandits along the road, hostile states, etc. If you've ever heard of American pioneers (e.g. the Oregon Trail), this sounds like doing that twice a year.
Now, this idea isn't that bad, and if you want a biannual epic journey for your society, then go ahead. But there are some ways to make this idea more plausible.
Transhumance
Transhumance is a type of pastoral nomadism (read: people herding animals) where the livestock is migrated seasonally to winter and summer pastures. Transhumance has been practiced by many cultures on every continent (except Antarctica), but it has been most commonly practiced in mountainous areas. Why? Because the steep altitude variations found in the mountains create a lot of variation in climate. That's why you will often see "highlands" as a separate climate zone on climate maps; it's too much hassle to try and map all the climates in such a small area.
This idea works better than the original idea because it's much easier to move herds of livestock than to plant crops everywhere you go. Furthermore, the livestock themselves provide a motive to move. You can't keep a herd grazing on one patch of land for too long, or it will become barren and they'll starve, so you have to keep them moving.
You could implement this idea in a few ways. First, you could have the whole village move every season. This would work best if the winter and summer pastures were a ways away. On the other hand, you could have a sedentary village in the middle of two pastures. This would work best in a mountainous region where the winter and summer pastures are close together. The first idea would probably jive with your concept a bit better.
However, there is a better way...
Migratory farmers
This group of people moves around to different cities and villages, planting and harvesting crops. They set up semi-permanent villages wherever they go. They do not live as a society on their own but are on the outskirts of a larger society. This might be as close as you get to a migratory agriculturist society.
Edit: Clarified why mountains create large climate variations

There's another reason transhumance works better in mountain areas: The climate changes much faster with altitude than with latitude.  It's a day or two's cattle drive down from the high summer pastures to the winter valleys, but a couple of months north/south hike to make much difference on flat ground.  Of course an intermediate version is possible, with not very high moorland summer grazing and winters on the coast with the benefit of the sea for warmth

A number of the American Indian tribes would plant hardy crops that didn't need much tending and leave them behind, and then come back and harvest them as they made their yearly loop through different areas.  This could pair well with moving herds of livestock.

@Chris H
That's what I was trying to say with, "Because mountains create an environment where there is a lot of variation in climate in a small area." It's probably good to outright state what I merely implied, though.

@rhf I thought that was what you were getting at, but there seemed to be a little gap so I wasn't quite sure.

Or: you CAN'T grow enough food in the summe (because of bad soil), so you need to catch all 4 growing seasons, two in the cold place (while the hot place get's too torched) and 2 in the hot place (while the cold place freezes over). Your initial statement makes a big assertment here that isn't that safe

@Hobbamok Maybe, but the question doesn't mention anything so severe in terms of climate, so I assumed the climates were relatively moderate compared to, "Oh crap, I'll be frozen/boiled alive (literally)."

@RHF sorry but that's a strawman. All we need is not being able to grow food in the winter and struggling in the summer. It could even be normal warm in the summer if that means the climate keeps the rain away. Nobody said anything about any unrealistic extremes.

You already have a justification
Why is the goal that you mention — to grow multiple crops a year — not justification for your society? So long as the value of those crops outweighs the cost of moving biannually it sounds like you've answered your own question — and the circumstance is similar to almost any nomadic society, so it's beyond believable.
It would be harder to justify this in a modern society where mass transport (economy of scale) would cost less than changing towns... but the tradition would likely become something similar to Finnish mökit.
The real problem is protecting assets
Your bigger problem is rationalizing how the empty town stays viable. If it had any intrinsic value (permanent buildings, furniture, etc.) it would be easy pickings for unscrupulous bandits or, worse, for whole societies that would move in because it's convenient. At that point your people are fighting a war against an entrenched foe.
You could perhaps work out symbiotic societies that would move in and out of the central town, keeping that town occupied all year round. But if the town had that kind of value, one of those societies would have chosen to stop traveling. So what we're really talking about are towns and/or areas that are truly unusable for half the year.
Which means you need to make each area unusable for half the year
That means the only way to really rationalize this is via ecology. Oversimplifying the solution something awful, it's like saying that one town experiences its monsoon season for half the year and the other town experiences its monsoon season during the opposite half of the year. During the monsoon season, so much rain falls that it's impossible for anyone to live there unless they pack in six months of food and plenty of Nyquil. To make a long story short, something about each area (most likely the climate) makes that area uninhabitable for half the year (give or take).
Are there any terrestrial examples?
Of a city-dwelling people? not that I can think of. Humanity has chosen to live in remarkably inhospitable places and they do that by storing food. But in many cases (probably most cases) those people are (or were before modern technologies made things easier) nomadic with temporary housing (tents, teepees, yurts...). And, as I said, there's the problem of a well-built building being so valuable that it's hard to imagine someone not moving in and claiming squatter's rights.
Which means half of this is developing the justification, and the other half is ignoring the consequences for the sake of your story
Keep in mind that you don't need to rationalize every detail. In fact, the history of fiction is one of ignoring details for the sake of the story's message. If you're dealing with a medievalesque period, then you can rationalize how nobody in their right mind would ever occupy another tribe's/society's anti-village because (e.g.) their god would punish them for it. This is going to be a story-based issue (one that's not suitable to have answered here) because it's a reason why someone wouldn't choose to break the taboo and character choices are off-topic.

If it was 150℉ in the summer in the south and -50℉ in the winter in the north, that would probably do it.

You don't occupy another tribe's village because doing so means either moving in earlier than ideal, or spending the bad season in the wrong place.  Either way, the returning villagers are in better shape than you, and they're angry.

@Mark Good point! But not enough, I'm afraid. One person's tough living is another person's heavenly paradise. Consider the trappers of the American west. We can debate forever, but it's hard for me to believe that a whole village full of good medieval-era permanent housing would ever stay that way for long. Unless, as my answer suggests, the OP creates environments that are uninhabitable.

@Ajedi32 A 150°F seasonal average (highs ranging from 120°F to 170°F) might work, but it would take more than a seasonal average of -50°F. People live permanently in Alaska with that temperature and worse. Humans can handle much more cold than they can hot - but many (perhaps most) plants require a seasonal average of about 80°F. So one side needs a temperature swing of 70°F, which is hard enough, but the other would need a swing of 150°F. Those two swings will be hard to rationalize. maybe with an axial tilt of about 70°. Maybe.

Nowhere in Alaska has a seasonal average of -50 F. At those temperatures there are only a very few settlements in Yakutia with a total population in the hundreds, the coldest major city is Yakutsk which only averages -40. I question a medieval-era civilization living permanently in those conditions, but in any case they'd need housing beyond another tribe's summer houses. They could adapt them, of course, but if you're going to build a settlement anyway it makes sense to do it where someone isn't going to fight you for it next summer.

I believe theft might be the greater risk here. Even the houses themselves might not be safe if parts can be re-used. E.g. wood can always be re-used.

@user111403 they're not living in those conditions, they're avoiding those conditions. It's an extreme like that which could rationalize why nobody messes with their off-season stuff.

@JBH yes, exactly. I'm arguing that a seasonal average of -50F is probably plenty to achieve that purpose.

There's another point to mention in here, which is house maintenance. If your winter house suffers season average of -40F, you have high chances to return to rubble instead of a house just because it has caved in due to extreme snow. If your summer house suffers season average of 120F, there's a high risk of your house being burned to the ground when you return. Building houses that can sustain that environment without maintenance is possible, but VERY expensive for a medieval society, but rebuilding houses each second year is also prohibitively expensive.

You could state that the world has an exceptionally powerful and rapid glaciation cycle.  In the winter the lowlands are temperate while the uplands are completely blanketed in ice and snow metres deep.  In the summer the uplands are clear, while the lowlands become a marshy swamp infested with unpleasant diseases and insects.
Such rapid (de)glaciation is probably not at all scientifically plausible, and even in a pure-fantasy story it might be more believable on a cycle of a few terrestrial years, but the TL;DR would be that the people move because they have to, and the food moving with them is the afterthought.

I was going to suggest a similar idea :-)
You could add too that in the uplands, there is a unique flora that has an extremely high value, and the village relies on it for its "main income". Something like a special flower that has exceptional medicinal value, or a special spice...
And because of the extreme and quick glaciation, noone will come there in the summer to sack their empty village. Also, only them know how to harvest those flowers.

Your world is only habitable past a certain altitude, think Larry Niven's Plateau: https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Plateau as the Ur example.
The deadly lower atmosphere both ascends and descends with the seasons or a tidal effect from the world's satellite planet and is extremely fertilizing for the soil.
This way, people need to rush down to quickly grow/harvest a crop when the lower atmosphere wanes and make it back before it returns and and there's a lot of inbuilt drama. It makes sense to have duplicate permanent towns, because no one could take it over/rob it while you're away.

You can justify it just like the Russian people, owning a дача (dacha). It is a small plot of land bought by people normally living in the urban areas, land that is used for gardening. They usually build a very small house on that land (while others build very big houses - a different discussion).
While some people visit the dacha only occasionally, as a garden, some others literally move there for the entire gardening time, from early spring to later autumn. Even if they have jobs, when they return home, they return to the dacha, not to the city.
While some of those people live at the dacha for the gardening, others do it especially for the added benefit of the silence, cleaner air, surrounding nature etc.

As a side note, Russian nobility had a common habit of having two mansions, one for summertime and one for wintertime, up to the emperors, for example, the Zimniy (Winter) palace in St.Petersburg. This habit went down to rich people who had money to both sustain two homes and travel back and forth, although peasants didn't have that luxury (and IIRC don't even now).

@Vesper: Very true, but OP's question did not give me any vibe of nobility :)  see "grow... harvest... geese..."

@Vesper does raise the point that people want to live in different places in different seasons, given the choice. It just needs to be convenient enough

Sounds a bit like Prague, a summer / weekend 'house' seemed pretty common when I was there, some little more than glorified beach huts of course, but most had mains water and electricity as far as I could tell (I recall some good weekend barbecues) others a bit more substantial than that, the mother of one I knew moved into theirs after she was widowed (giving them the town house) so they were livable

If you want them to migrate long distance you have to resort to a different strategy. Most dual living people, which we have here too, migrate between lowlands during winter and highlands during summer.
Planet has a very high tilt and takes very long to go around its star. Also make it so that the planet is cooler on average then Earth. This means long winters will get unlivably cold. Most plants would die, some trees will simply freeze and wait to be thawed. Any animals stay behind will hibernate. Most animals will be migratory in this situation, including humans.

You honestly have nothing to prove for this one. I can't remember if it was the Persian empire or the Sumerians but it was literally the case that the nation which once ruled an empire spanning the known world would alternate between living in 2 sets of homes depending on the time of year. These weren't poor people either, they were the ruling nation of a large empire that could demand food from others if they felt like it. I think they just moved around to avoid periods of high heat in the one home and excessive cold in the other. So they migrated for quality of life alone, not even survival.
If you okay with more fantastical explanations, you could make the claim that there are insects or animals that are so dangerous in the hot season of the year that your people have to evacuate to a worse area while the ferocious insects are about - and then are forced back into the first area while the insects are dormant to try stockpile up enough food to survive again.

Why would you need justification at all? Many people have more than one home and move between them as they please or as the need drives them.
Think "pensionados" from northern and western Europe spending the cold and wet winter months in Spain or Italy because of the nicer climate (which for them is too hot in summer).
Or a good friend of mine who has multiple homes and stays at each for several months a year, depending on where her business needs her (she owns the company), moving her entire household between locations. Basically she got tired of living out of a suitcase 10 months out of the year, spending several months at a time away from home in the same hotel, so bought houses in the cities and countries she most frequently visits.

Ursula LeGuin has a fantastic short story with a very similar premise called "Seasons of the Ansarac" in her collection Changing Planes. If I recall correctly, the planet it's set on has a very long seasonal cycle relative to Earth, and the bird-like people migrate between two permanent homes when the seasons change.
It makes more sense when each season lasts for decades, but might be worth reading to get inspiration for something similar on a shorter timescale - plus it's just a great short story. Each 'home' is very different, and the people's lifestyle and societal structure changes dramatically between the two, and her exploration of the impact of that huge migration on people's lives is very interesting.
